# C# Regex How to replace multiple quotation marks respectively in a string with « and »

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace the quotation marks in some strings. Although, this have to be done respectively and using « ». It is not definite that it will begin and end with quotation marks.

For example I have this string:

> "THIS IS "inner1" THE MAIN "inner2" SENTENCE"

I want to change it to:

> «THIS IS «inner1» THE MAIN «inner2» SENTENCE»

**SOLUTION:**

With much help from [musefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/838807/musefan) (code is a bit different than his original solution since it is not definite that the string will begin and end with quotation marks). It is not done by linking in some way the pairs of quotation marks but by replacing them if they follow or followed by a whitespace and then check and apply replacement, if necessary, to the first and last character of the string provided.

```
using System;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "\"THIS IS \"inner1\" THE MAIN \"inner2\" SENTENCE\"";
        string result=input;
        //Replace quotes that follow space with « and replace quotes that precede space with »
        result = result.Replace(" \"", " «").Replace("\" ", "» ");

        //if first character is " then replace with «
        if (result.Substring(0, 1) == "\"")
            result = "«" + result.Substring(1);

        //get last character of the string
        char last = result[result.Length - 1];
        //if it is " then replace it with »
        if (last.ToString() == "\"")
            result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1) + "»";

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What will you do if there are 3 quotation marks?

Comment: hmm ig its better if you use single quote ' in some place of it

Comment: How do you know which are the quotations which are linked? because I believe there will be no solution which could prevent your from having this kind of result: «THIS IS »inner1« THE MAIN »inner2« SENTENCE»

Comment: In the meantime, read the docs for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: First of all, you need to provide your attempted code if you want out help. Second of all, what are you exact rules? Is nesting forbidden (aside from the initial outer quotes)? or is it to be calculated based on which side the space character is? The problem is that without very specific rules, there could be multiple valid outputs

Comment: hmm would you like to do it in non-regex style?

Comment: A potentially simpler approach, if the text minds its punctuation, is to change all quotation marks directly preceding a character to opening guillemets, and all quotation marks directly following a character to closing guillemets. This can be done with zero-width assertions in regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is: how do you know when a quote should be the start of a new set, or the end of an existing one? There are many possible use cases that might require differently handling.

So, I have made the assumption that you are going to use space characters to work out if the quote is the start of a new set, or if it is the end of an existing one. The reason for this assumption is that it is the most obvious logic to ensure you get the desired result.

With that in mind, it becomes very simple:

```
// First remove the out quotes, we will manually change them at the end.
string result = input.Substring(1, input.Length - 2);
// Replace quotes that follow space with « and replace quotes that precede space with »
result = result.Replace(" \"", " «").Replace("\" ", "» ");
// Add the outer chevrons around the result.
result = string.Format("«{0}»", result);
```

[Here is a working example](https://ideone.com/vzj4Bo).

---

**Disclaimer**: Please keep in mind that this answer is provided based on the sample data you have given. There are many possible inputs where it may be required to re-think the rules/logic in order to achieve the desired result. However, I cannot cater for that without knowing those additional requirements.

Feel free to edit your question if you have more specific requirements and I will try to update my answer, however you may need to prompt me with a comment so I know you have changed your requirements.

Comment: Does this work for the outer quotes that have no whitespace?

Comment: @LanceToth: Yes, as we handle these manually. I have added a link to demo

Comment: Through your code works fine but it takes 2.31sec for single string to format, it will cause freeze in ui if a long string or multiple string are used to format, but nice code *Thumbs Up*

Comment: @Agent_Orange: 2.31 seconds??? What are you running it on? Haha, it will be no where near that slow

Comment: oops i got it, looks like its website problem, anyways i was using rextester to compile it :D, forgive me

Comment: It is not definite it the string will begin and end with quotation marks so I have edited your code a bit. Editing my question now.